# Are wildcards expanded in the shell or the command which the shell forked?

Tags: linux, shell, wildcard

For example, let's assume I have those files in my current work directory:

`demo.txt`, `text.txt`, `temp.txt`, `audio.mp3`.

When I run this command in the shell:

```bash
ls *.txt
```

What happened under the neath?

Does shell expand it to `ls demo.txt text.txt temp.txt` first and put it into `argv` then fork `ls`?

Or does it do nothing but put `ls *.txt` directly into `argv` and then fork `ls`?

Comment: It expands first, then spawns the command. If you quote `*.txt` with single-quotes, then it's passed verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux (and Unix variants in general) wildcard expansion is done by the shell before invoking the command. (Unless explicitly suppressed with quotes.)

In other operating systems (e.g. DOS, Windows) wildcards are always passed verbatim and their expansion is the responsibility of the command.